# Проблема при переходе с MySQL на MySQLi

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Всем привет. Попробую объяснить суть моей проблемы - есть php файл, который является классом, в котором куча методов (функций). И во многих методах, в конце, был такой код:

```
function getSitee($uid) {
        $q = "SELECT id FROM tx5_users WHERE sit1 = $uid or sit2 = $uid";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
        return $this->mysql_result($result); //так было в оригинале
}
```

или, например, вот так:

```
function getFieldLevel($vid, $field) {
        $q = "SELECT f" . $field . " FROM tx5_fdata WHERE vref = $vid";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
        return mysql_result($result, 0); //так было в оригинале
}
```

Но затем потребовалось перейти с MySQL на MySQLi и тут возникли проблемы:

1. В первой функции можно заменить `mysql_result()` на `mysqli_fetch_all()`
2. Во второй функции заменить `mysql_result()` на `mysqli_fetch_all()` уже не удается (((. Поэтому я написал функцию:

   function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) {
   $res->data_seek($row);
   $datarow = $res->fetch_array();
   return $datarow[$field];
   }

Но если я вставляю эту функцию в этот же класс, то вижу такую ошибку:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 1540**

Как победить ошибку?

Comment: а чем не устраивает mysqli_fetch_row() или mysqli_fetch_assoc()? и если можно поподробнее что вы хотите получить во втором случае?

Comment: используйте PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_fetch_all() принимает результат запроса в виде объекта mysqli_result. mysqli_result это встроенный в PHP класс, поэтому переименуйте ваш вариант функции, чтобы избежать конфликта имен. И еще - функция mysqli_query() возвращает объект класса mysqli_result для запроса SELECT, а mysql_query() возвращает resource, который является передаваемым в mysql_result() параметром, тоесть mysql_result() не в состоянии обработать (скорее всего, на практике не проверял) возвращаемый mysqli_query() результат.